# Diffusion/Heat equation, weak maximum principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider the problem: 
$$u_t -div(A(x) \nabla u) +a(x) u = f $$
$$u(\sigma,t)=0 $$
$$u(x,0)=g(x) $$

and its variational formulation

$$ \lt \dot{u(t)},v \gt_* + B(u(t),v;t) =(f,v)_{L^2} \quad \forall v \in H^1_0(\Omega) \quad a.a. t\in(0,T) $$

if $$B(u,v;t)=\int_{\Omega}A(x)\nabla u \nabla v  \ + \int_{\Omega}a(x)uv$$

is weakly cohercive,
than the equation satisfies a "Maximum" Principle: 
$$ f \geq 0, \ g \geq 0 \Rightarrow u\geq0  $$

I was wandering, is there any generalization of the problem?

For example the equation could be:

$$u_t -div(A(x) \nabla u) + div(\vec{b}u) + \vec{c} \nabla u +a(x) u = f $$

and the boundary conditions different, but I couldn't find it anywhere